# jQuery syntax to find elements with opacity property

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following functions which controls the opacity property of four images with ids namely bike,car,bus and walk. This is the code I wrote to change opacity each time when an image is clicked.

```
function changebike() {
    $('#bike').css('opacity','1.0');
    $('#car').css('opacity','0.5');
    $('#bus').css('opacity','0.5');
    $('#walk').css('opacity','0.5');
};

function changecar() {
    $('#bike').css('opacity','0.5');
    $('#car').css('opacity','1.0');
    $('#bus').css('opacity','0.5');
    $('#walk').css('opacity','0.5');
};

function changebus() {
    $('#bike').css('opacity','0.5');
    $('#car').css('opacity','0.5');
    $('#bus').css('opacity','1.0');
    $('#walk').css('opacity','0.5');
};

function changewalk() {
    $('#bike').css('opacity','0.5');
    $('#car').css('opacity','0.5');
    $('#bus').css('opacity','0.5');
    $('#walk').css('opacity','1.0');
};
```

I need to write a function like this

```
function changeItem(item) {
    var elements = $('*').filter(function() {
                        var options=['0.5','1.0'];
                        return $.inArray($(this).css('opacity'), options) > -1;
                    });
    elements.css('opacity','0.5');
    $(item).css('opacity','1.0');
};
```

In HTML, I call the function like this

```
<img src="bike.png" id="bike" onclick="changeItem('#bike')" />
```

However, the above code doesn't work. Please point out my mistake and correct the code. :-) Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like, but you have to define your ID's

```
function changeItem(item) {
    var elementIDs = ["#bike", "#car", "#bus", "#walk"];
    $.each(elementIDs, function(k, v){
        var op = 0.5;
        if( item == v )
            op = 1;
        $(v).css('opacity', op)
    });
};
```

Comment: Superb! Thank you so much.. Worked perfectly.
One question, Why should we pass (k,v) in the function, when k isn't being used?

Comment: Because you get 2 params, if we only define the first, it will be the index, and not the value, and it's the value we want. Unless you want to do `elementIDs[k]` instead of `v`, which gives the value.

Answer (score 1):

you dont have to call the function via the ugly "onclick" event when using jQuery.
i haven't tested this code ... its right out of my head ... hope it works :)

HTML

```
<div id="bike">bike</div>
<div id="car">car</div>
<div id="bus">bus</div>
<div id="walk">walk</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#bike').click(changeOpacity(this));
    $('#car').click(changeOpacity(this));
    $('#bus').click(changeOpacity(this));
    $('#walk').click(changeOpacity(this));

    function changeOpacity(target){
        var ids = ['#bike','#car','#bus','#walk'];
        for(var id in ids){
            $(id).css('opacity',.5);
            if(ids[id] == target.attr('id')){
                $(id).css('opacity',1);
            }
        }    
    }

});
```

Comment: No problem. I'm using ontouchstart event for mobile browsers :-).. but this seems like a way to go too.